# Using historical imagery Google Maps API for Business

Tags: api, maps, google, aerial-photography, photos

Is there a way using Google Maps API for Business to see historical aerial imagery, like you can in Google Earth Pro, with the slider bar they have at the top of GEP?

Comment: I think not. The cheeky answer is that most of the imagery in Google Maps could be considered historical, outside of major cities. I think it is possible that Mapbox might be able to do something like this and I know they have much more up to date imagery generally.